# How to check whether the text in an HTML tag is preceeded by other HTML tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to do something like this:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(htmlText);

string innerText = element.Value;

foreach(XElement child in element.Elements())
{

   if(this child preceeds the element's innerText in original string)
   {
      // do something
   }
   else
   {
      // do something else
   }
}
```

For example, lets say if I have the following HTML:

`<a href='/test.html'><strong>Note:</strong>Do something <b>but beware.</b></a>`

I would like to know that the **STRONG** tag appeared before "Do something" and the **B** tag appeared after.

Please help...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: you need http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @vishalsharma can you please post a code example?

Comment: @Ted At the moment, I am looking if there is a clean way of doing it, otherwise I will have to do magic string parsing with regexes and what not which I am trying to avoid